# Generate valid binary search tree with Python hypothesis by paramertizing recursive calls

Tags: python, unit-testing, property-based-testing, python-hypothesis

How do you parametrize recursive strategies in the Python hypothesis library?

I'd like to test that the `is_valid_bst` function works by generating valid BSTs with a [recursive strategy](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html?highlight=recursive#hypothesis.strategies.recursive).

```
import hypothesis as hp
from hypothesis import strategies as hps


class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.val = x
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

  def __repr__(self):
    if not self.left and not self.right:
      return f'TreeNode({self.val})'
    return f'TreeNode({self.val}, left={self.left}, right={self.right}'


def is_valid_bst(node):
  if not node:
    return True

  is_valid = True
  if node.left:
    is_valid = is_valid and node.val > node.left.val
  if node.right:
    is_valid = is_valid and node.val < node.right.val

  if not is_valid:
    return False

  return is_valid_bst(node.left) and is_valid_bst(node.right)


@hps.composite
def valid_bst_trees(draw, strategy=None, min_value=None, max_value=None):
  val = draw(hps.integers(min_value=min_value, max_value=max_value))
  node = TreeNode(val)
  node.left = draw(strategy)
  node.right = draw(strategy)
  return node


def gen_bst(tree_strategy, min_value=None, max_value=None):
  return hps.integers(min_value=min_value, max_value=max_value).flatmap(
      lambda val: valid_bst_trees(
          strategy=tree_strategy, min_value=min_value, max_value=max_value))


@hp.given(hps.recursive(hps.just(None), gen_bst))
def test_is_valid_bst_works(node):
  assert is_valid_bst(node)
```

Comment: How would you construct an instance of your BST class outside of a test?  The code you've shown doesn't actually work (e.g. nodes not comparable, strategy never assigns `right`...) so I can't help much on the Hypothesis side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  My main misunderstanding was:

- The tree_strategy created by the hypothesis.recursive strategy is safe to draw from multiple times and will generate appropriate recursion.

A few other gotchas:

- The base case needs both `None` and a singleton tree.  With only `None`, you'll only generate None.
- For the singleton tree, you must generate a new tree every time.  Otherwise, you'll end up with cycles in the tree since each node is the same tree.  Easiest way to accomplish this is `hps.just(-111).map(TreeNode)`.
- You'll need to overwrite the base case if it's a singleton tree to respect `min_value` and `max_value`.

Full working solution:

```
import hypothesis as hp
from hypothesis import strategies as hps


class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.val = x
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

  def __repr__(self):
    if not self.left and not self.right:
      return f'TreeNode({self.val})'
    return f'TreeNode({self.val}, left={self.left}, right={self.right}'


def is_valid_bst(node):
  if not node:
    return True

  is_valid = True
  if node.left:
    is_valid = is_valid and node.val > node.left.val
  if node.right:
    is_valid = is_valid and node.val < node.right.val

  if not is_valid:
    return False

  return is_valid_bst(node.left) and is_valid_bst(node.right)


@hps.composite
def valid_bst_trees(
    draw, tree_strategy, min_value=None, max_value=None):
  """Returns a valid BST.

  Idea is to pick an integer VAL in [min_value, max_value) for this tree and
  and use it as a constraint for the children by parameterizing
  `tree_strategy` so that:

  1. The left child value is in [min_value, VAL).
  2. The right child value is in (VAL, min_value].
  """
  # We're drawing either a None or a singleton tree.
  node = draw(tree_strategy)
  if not node:
    return None
  # Can't use implicit boolean because the values might be falsey, e.g. 0.
  if min_value is not None and max_value is not None and min_value >= max_value:
    return None

  # Overwrite singleton tree.val with one that respects min and max value.
  val = draw(hps.integers(min_value=min_value, max_value=max_value))
  node.val = val

  node.left = draw(valid_bst_trees(
      tree_strategy=tree_strategy,
      min_value=min_value,
      max_value=node.val - 1))
  node.right = draw(valid_bst_trees(
      tree_strategy=tree_strategy,
      min_value=node.val + 1,
      max_value=max_value))
  return node


def gen_bst(tree_strategy, min_value=None, max_value=None):
  return valid_bst_trees(
      tree_strategy=tree_strategy,
      min_value=min_value,
      max_value=max_value)


# Return a new, distinct tree node every time to avoid self referential trees.
singleton_tree = hps.just(-111).map(TreeNode)


@hp.given(hps.recursive(hps.just(None) | singleton_tree, gen_bst))
def test_is_valid_bst_works(node):
  assert is_valid_bst(node)


# Simple tests to demonstrate how the TreeNode works
def test_is_valid_bst():
  assert is_valid_bst(None)
  assert is_valid_bst(TreeNode(1))

  node1 = TreeNode(1)
  node1.left = TreeNode(0)
  assert is_valid_bst(node1)

  node2 = TreeNode(1)
  node2.left = TreeNode(1)
  assert not is_valid_bst(node2)

  node3 = TreeNode(1)
  node3.left = TreeNode(0)
  node3.right = TreeNode(1)
  assert not is_valid_bst(node3)
```